# Can anybody identify this 1900-1933 uniform (possibly German)

Tags: military, identification, uniform, imperial-germany

I believe this image to be taken around 1900-1933. I also believe it to be a German uniform but I'm not certain. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Text]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cap is that of a German [Kaiserliche Marine Deckoffizier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deckoffizier) until 1920.

> **Deckoffizier**
> Häufig aus der einfachen Laufbahn der Matrosen aufgestiegen, berät er als Spezialist seines Fachs den Kapitän oder die anderen mit der Schiffsleitung betrauten Offiziere. Typische Dienststellungen sind die Position als Steuermann, Bootsmann, Feuerwerker (Schiffsartillerist), Maschinist, Mechaniker, Materialienverwalter oder Torpeder (Torpedo-Experte).
>
> > **deck officer**
> > As a specialist in his field, he often rose from the simple career of a sailor and advises the captain or the other officers entrusted with the ship's management.  Typical positions are the position as helmsman, boatswain, fireworker (ship artilleryman), machinist, mechanic, materials manager or torpedo (torpedo expert).
>
> From the German language [Warrant Officer – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_Officer):
>
> > In German-speaking countries, these roughly correspond to the historical ranks **Feldwebelleutnant** and in the Navy **Deckoffizier**.

| Deckoffizier | Seeoffizier |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The images are from:

- [Kaiserliche Marine Deckoffizier Schirmmütze](https://www.kaisersbunker.com/km/km16.htm)
- [Kaiserliche Marine Seeoffizier Schirmmütze](https://www.kaisersbunker.com/km/km18.htm)

  - commissioned officer

which shows further images and detailed explanations in english.

Further information can be found here (German only):

- [Uniformen der Kaiserlichen Marine – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformen_der_Kaiserlichen_Marine#Deckoffiziere)

Comment: So sort of like a high-ranking sergeant in the Army?

Comment: @T.E.D. In the German language [Warrant Officer – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_Officer): *In German-speaking countries, these roughly correspond to the historical ranks **Feldwebelleutnant** and in the Navy **Deckoffizier***. *Feldwebelleutnant* would be your suggested 'high-ranking sergeant'.

Comment: @T.E.D., it would be a former sergeant promoted to a spot halfway between NCO and real officer.

Comment: According to my trusty 1934 USNA Naval Phraseology text book, a Deckoffizier is, indeed, the equivalent of a Warrant Officer.